# php error log template

Tags: php, nginx, error-handling

I've configured an error log to on, I've set the path to error file log. Errors are saving. The problem is that I have a weird construst of the message:

```
2015/12/22 00:35:38 [error] 12152#0: *57 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/movie/application/modules/frontend/controllers/IndexController.php on line 11" while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.38.16.66, server: xxxx.yy, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xxxx.yy", referrer: "xxxx.yy"
```

I would like to have it a bit simpler something like:

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/movie/application/modules/frontend/controllers/IndexController.php
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you explain how did you configure that error log...

Comment: how will you ever know when an error occured when you remove the date information? Also, you tagged this nginx, so are we talking about the nginx log or the php error log?

Comment: You are right, date is neccessary. We are talking about php's errors but the application is running on nginx.

Comment: @Amarnasan, I've just set log errors on in php configure files. Thats all.